# Linked pictures are duplicating themselves almost like a mouse pointer trail when I move the group they're in

Tags: microsoft-excel, links, pictures

[image: Linked Picture Duplicated]

My linked pictures are duplicating themselves almost like a mouse pointer trail when I move the group they're in. I have them grouped with some charts (15 on the sheet) I have a few pivot tables on other tabs that are fairly large but not unreasonably, (6MB raw data prior to loading to pivot is the largest).

I'm using Excel 2016 (Office 365). **The file is hosted on our SharePoint drive**, but I'm editing with the desktop version. (Excel online doesn't accept the linked pictures.)

Normally I can click on a linked picture and the formula will show up in the formula bar where I can edit the link. In this case there is no selection window on clicking on the picture; I can delete them sometimes but the screen refresh seems super laggy and I can't tell if it was deleted; I don't get a formula bar. If I double click, it does take me to the correct linked cell. I've tried saving and closing, I've tried re-calculating workbook. How can I get Excel to update/refresh the picture's display? I believe I've done it before and the duplicated pictures seemed like they were acting like a picture "trails" (like a mouse pointer trail) because I've seen them all disappear and everything goes back to normal, but I can't seem to get that it to happen right now.

**Update 1**

The pointer trail thing seems to be close to the issue because tooltips keep popping up and staying far too long just while I'm moving the mouse around the workbook. The tooltips aren't even relevant as in the snip I'm on a different worksheet tab than any graphs.

**Update 2:**

So I think the slow workbook and the second snip of strange tool tips are a symptom of having almost 20k linked pictures due to this bug. You can see in the snip that this is picture number 19398.  I need to find a VBA to delete them all and start over linking them I think....

[image: Linked Picture 20k]

**Update 3:**
I found with the "tell me what you want to do" the *find and select pane*, it doesn't look like there are that many pictures after all.
(Unless it is just truncating results invisibly, but the scroll bar isn't tiny.)
**Update 4:**
Pending better information, I'll try dragging the pictures in a variety of ways to see if I can identify when exactly the duplication happens or doesn't happen. Now that I have the find and select pane, it is much less worrisome and I can try to get the steps to re-produce it.

**Update 5:**

I moved the graph and moved it back. In the undo history I see: move object, move object. I got 1 extra visible picture and I also got in the find and select pane pictures 19768-19774, these still exist after "undoing".  Then I clicked save and the extra pictures got cleaned up and deleted automatically.

**Update 6:**

I resized a picture, it duplicated itself, I didn't have it selected after the re-sizing. I pressed save, the duplicate went away.

With pic:
[image: Picture duplication in selection pane]

**Update 7**

This issue does not happen if the file is not hosted on SharePoint. But as soon as I add a file with linked pictures to the SharePoint drive, the duplication issue starts happening.

Comment: These look like graphical artifacts due to an underpowered system or out of date graphics drivers. Please check for updated graphics drivers on your computer and check for updates to Windows and Office.

Comment: I have used the *find and select pane* as a temporary fix to select and delete the extra pictures, I'm pretty sure this issue will come back so I'll leave the question open as I haven't figured out what is causing the duplication in the first place yet.

Answer (score 0):

This was indeed a bug and was solved by installing the latest windows 10 update(didn't fix it) and repairing office(It first said it was up-to-date). (I had this issue on two machines which is why I didn't do this sooner.) I've repaired the first machine's office and it required uninstalling some 64 bit components (Share-point designer) saying they don't get along with my 32 bit version of office, so I'll see if that is the same for the other machine as well.

Comment: This solution worked for the desktop, did the same steps on the laptop (Minus share-point designer) and the problems still persists on my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problem in my dashboards.
I almost deleted all linked pictures, not to use it anymore.
BUT
I turned off auto-saving and the issue is gone!